# Can I combine multiple update statements while keeping functionality?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm going through a stored procedure and I was trying to optimize it when I came  across about 13 update statements similar to below. I was wondering if anyone had a better solution than this. I know I can use case statements or coalesce and this would be semantically the same, but just bear in mind that all of the columns will always be updated. This probably won't cause you any problems, but I may have a high transactional volume so this approach could cause concurrency issues.

```
UPDATE  COGS
SET     Revenue = 0
WHERE   Revenue IS NULL
        AND monthDate = @targetCOGSdate;

UPDATE  COGS
SET     Costs = 0
WHERE   Costs IS NULL
        AND monthDate = @targetCOGSdate;

UPDATE  COGS
SET     Disposal = 0
WHERE   Disposal IS NULL
        AND monthDate = @targetCOGSdate;

UPDATE  COGS
SET     Trans = 0
WHERE   Trans IS NULL
        AND monthDate = @targetCOGSdate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE COGS
    SET Revenue = COALESCE(Revenue, 0),
        Costs = COALESCE(Costs, 0),
        Disposal = COALESCE(Disposal, 0),
        Trans = COALESCE(Trans, 0)
    WHERE monthDate = @targetCOGSdate AND
          (Revenue IS NULL OR Costs IS NULL OR Disposal IS NULL OR Trans IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce` expressions to set columns to 0 if they are null:

```
UPDATE  COGS
SET Revenue  = coalesce(Revenue, 0),
    Costs    = coalesce(Costs, 0),
    Disposal = coalesce(Disposal, 0),
    Trans    = coalesce(Trans, 0)
WHERE (Revenue IS NULL or Costs IS NULL or Disposal IS NULL or Trans IS NULL)
  AND monthDate = @targetCOGSdate;
```

But why are you doing this? I'd keep the NULLs!